# Python: idiomatic way to create new dataframes by slicing an existing df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the most pythonic way to create new dataframes by slicing an existing df?

Lets say I have a dataframe with some something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

begin = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 00:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 05:00:00')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['EvaluationUtc','Horizon','type','BZ','Value'])
A = pd.date_range(start= begin, end= end, periods=5)
B = ['D-2','D-1','D-1','D-1','Selected']
C = ['ND','ND','ND','ND','ND']
D = ['NO1','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO1']
E = [1568,1324,5678,4321,4564]
df.EvaluationUtc = A
df.Horizon = B
df.type = C
df.BZ = D
df.Value = E
```

So it looks like this

```
df
Out[2]: 
          EvaluationUtc   Horizon type   BZ  Value
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00       D-2   ND  NO1   1568
1 2023-01-02 01:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   1324
2 2023-01-03 02:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   5678
3 2023-01-04 03:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   4321
4 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Selected   ND  NO1   4564
```

Now lets pretend that this dataframe extends on for roughly 6 million more entries where we have similar values but for a range of different BZ's and a whole years worth of data in consecutive order. Something like this (shortened for effect):

```
          EvaluationUtc   Horizon type   BZ  Value
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00       D-2   ND  NO2   1568
1 2023-01-02 01:00:00       D-1   ND  NO2   1324
2 2023-01-03 02:00:00       D-1   ND  NO2   5678
3 2023-01-04 03:00:00       D-1   ND  NO2   4321
4 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Selected   ND  NO2   4564
...
101 2023-01-01 00:00:00       D-2   ND  NO1   1568
102 2023-01-02 01:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   1324
103 2023-01-03 02:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   5678
104 2023-01-04 03:00:00       D-1   ND  NO1   4321
105 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Selected   ND  NO1   4564
...
304 2023-01-01 00:00:00       D-2   ND  SO1   1568
305 2023-01-02 01:00:00       D-1   ND  SO1   1324
306 2023-01-03 02:00:00       D-1   ND  SO1   5678
307 2023-01-04 03:00:00       D-1   ND  SO1   4321
308 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Selected   ND  SO1   4564
```

I want to select a specific period that will contain all the BZ's values so I can sum them and plot them.

So first I find all forecasted data, this is the `type == D-2`. (I'll do the same for the other types).

```
forecast = df[(df['Horizon']== 'D-2') ]
forecast.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

Then I want to save the slices that contain the different BZ's for specific periods in separate dataframes so for example if I hard coded it I would write something like this:

```
forecast_Hour_1 = forecast[(forecast['EvaluationUtc'] == begin)].reset_index(drop = True)
forecast_Hour_2 = forecast[(forecast['EvaluationUtc'] == begin + timedelta(hours=1))].reset_index(drop = True)
forecast_Hour_3 = forecast[(forecast['EvaluationUtc'] == begin + timedelta(hours=2))].reset_index(drop = True)
...
```

So I would get something like this

```
forecast_Hour_10
Out[8]: 
    Unnamed: 0         EvaluationUtc Horizon   type   BZ     Value
0           54 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  NO4  1315.800
1          198 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  NO1  2266.700
2          342 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  NO3  1609.900
3          486 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  NO5  1399.300
4          630 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  DK1  1571.833
5          774 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  DK2   897.334
6          918 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND   FI  6626.428
7         1062 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  NO2  2636.300
8         1206 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  SE1   893.100
9         1350 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  SE2  1429.100
10        1494 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  SE4  1710.500
11        1638 2022-05-20 09:00:00     D-2     ND  SE3  2728.500
```

What is a better way to do it so I create the dataframes automatically rather than writing them out one by one?

Comment: For all the rows with `EvaluationUtc` not an exact hour, do you want to discard those or group them in with one of the dataframes?

Comment: All entries should be an exact hour. I made a simplified reproducible example, maybe i made a mistake?The actual dataframe works over 24 hourly periods, one entry for each hour for each BZ and each type, with the exception of D-1 having 3,4 or 5 entries depending on the date.

Comment: `pd.date_range` is inclusive, so in your example `periods=5` for `A` doesn't return hours.  You just won't need to the last couple of lines of my answer given this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `globals()` to assign variables in a loop:

```py
# dictionary of types and their respective codes
types = {"forecast": "D-2"}
# array of hours from begin to end
hours = pd.date_range(begin, end=end, freq="H")

# loop through each 
for t, code in types.items():
    # initial variable for filtered df
    globals()[t] = df[(df['Horizon']== code) ].reset_index(drop=True)

    # group based on mapping .EvaluationUtc with `hours`
    for j, k in globals()[t].groupby(
            globals()[t].EvaluationUtc.map(
                {h: (ind+1) for ind, h in enumerate(hours)}).
            fillna(0).astype(int)):
        globals()[f"{t}_Hour_{j}"] = k
    # delete the additional varaiable created for non-hour rows
    if f"{t}_Hour_0" in globals():
        del globals()[f"{t}_Hour_0"]
```

This first loops through the different types you in the dictionary (creating a dataframe of the filtered `df`), then loops through each group - where the rows are grouped on hour, mapped from `hours`.

Finally, if there are any datetime values that are not an hour then these will appear in `{type}_Hour_0` and this variable is deleted.

Comment: wow, that's insanely concise. Thanks.